# Camera Program Raspberry Pi Error Occurs return self.func(*args)

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I'm seeming to have some trouble with this code. I've been trying to code a program that hooks up to a hard button that when pressed, it will take a photo using the Raspberry Pi Camera and will display it in a Tkinter window on the screen, and will allow you to press a soft button that will be displayed to take another photo by pressing the hard button again. I'm using GPIO 4 to hook the  button up to the Raspberry Pi, but the hard button and the GPIO aren't the problem, the code is.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import picamera
import sys
from Tkinter import *
cam = picamera.PiCamera()
button1 = 4
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(button1, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
def command():
       pict()
       root.destroy()
       rootcreate()
def rootcreate():
       root = Tk()
       button = Button(root, text = 'Press to take another photo.', command = command)
       button.pack(side = BOTTOM)
       pic = PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/aando.gif")
       l = Label(root, image = pic)
       l.pack()
       root.mainloop()
       GPIO.cleanup()
def pict():
       global a
       a = 1
       global button1
       while a == 1:
              if GPIO.input(button1) == False:
                     GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
                     cam.capture("aando.gif")
                     rootcreate()
pict()
while 1 == 1:
       sys.stdout.flush()
```

The program runs fine the first press of the hard button, and makes the window pop up displaying the photo the camera took. However, when I press the soft button, it changes to the pressed-down position, but when I release my mouse, it just stays like that. It says that no errors have occurred yet, but when I opened up my command line to check for error messages (it was minimized) it started glitching out and sort of stamping the top bit of the command line across the screen. However, when I did click the hard button, a second Tkinter window popped up, but this time only containing the button, and not the photo. Pressing the hard button also did not destroy the 'root' window, but instead,   this error message popped up:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1437, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "buttoncam.py", line 11, in command
pict()
File "buttoncam.py", line 31, in pict
rootcreate()
File "buttoncam.py", line 19, in rootcreate
l = Label(root, image = pic)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2502, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2001, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

I searched up the `return self.func(*args)`, but everything that I read made no sense to me. I also tried to wrap my head around init functions, but all of it was way over my head. If someone could help me find a solution to this problem, that would be great.

Unfortunately, that's not yet the end of the problem. After closing all of the Tkinter windows, this error message pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "buttoncam.py", line 32, in <module>
pict()
File "buttoncam.py", line 28, in pict
if GPIO.input(button1) == False:
RuntimeError: Please set pin numbering mode using
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) or GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
```

I'm not too sure what's happening there, because as you can see, I've already set my pin numbering mode earlier in the code. If someone knew how to fix that, that would be really helpful.

Comment: You've got the camera working and that's great, but the next step is not quick: you must learn how to write an event-driven program.  Tkinter is fine for this purpose, but programs of this type do not have a simple linear execution path.  The mainloop function is actually a semi-infinite loop from which control doesn't return until the last Tkinter window is closed.  Event handlers define which functions get executed for each user action.  Work through a tutorial on Tkinter (there is one in "Python in a Nutshell"), and I'm sure there are others.

Comment: `mainloop` is more than _semi_-infinite. It's a truly infinite loop (well, as much as any infinite loop can be).

Comment: In addition to what @PaulCornelius said: With GUI programming you really should learn object oriented programming and writing a class instead of using `global` to have state across function calls.